# Prove that a power series converges and diverges at a particular point

Tags: complex-analysis

If the power series $\sum a_n (z+3-i)^n$ converges at $5i$ and diverges at $-3i$,then prove that the power series converges at $-2+5i$ and diverges at $2-3i$.

Proof :Since the power series converges at $5i$ so $\sum a_n (3+4i)<\infty $.Also $\sum a_n (3-4i)>\infty $.

To show that $\sum a_n (1+4i)<\infty$ and $\sum a_n (5-4i)>\infty $.How to prove this?Any help.

Comment: What is the radius of convergence of the power series?

Comment: since it converges in $5i$ so it is $|5i-(-3+i)|=5$ @DanielFischer

Comment: That tells you it's $\geqslant 5$. To see it's $= 5$, you need something more.

Comment: Also $|-3i-(-3+i)=-4i+3|=5$ so it is equal to $5$ ;right @DanielFischer

Comment: That's right. So what are $\lvert (-2 + 5i) - (-3+i)\rvert$ and $\lvert (2-3i) - (-3+i)\rvert$?

Comment: first one is $\sqrt 17 <5$ and second one is $\sqrt 41>5$.hence the result.right @DanielFischer

Answer (score 2):

As you have calculated $|5i-(-3+i)|$=$5$ and $|-3i-(-3+i)|$=$5$ and given that the series converges at $5i$ and diverges at $-3i$ , the *domain of convergence must be **$|z+3-i|$<5*** . Now you can easily verify that the points $-2+5i$ and $2-3i$ respectively lie inside and outside the domain of convergence.